# Unit Testing for provider which includes service with Replay Subject cannot read undefined of pipe

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am trying to cover a provider with Unit Test which includes a map at return with pipe.
But somehow the method is not a function says jasmine.

The provider it is used for Hotjar module.

This is my test.

```
fdescribe('UserRolesProvider', () => {
  let service: UserRolesProvider;
  let userServiceSpy: { onUserEvent: jasmine.Spy };

  beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
    userServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('UserService', ['onUserEvent']);

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [UserRolesProvider, { provide: UserService, useValue: userServiceSpy }],
    });
    service = TestBed.inject(UserRolesProvider);
  }));
  it('should have a service instance', () => {
    expect(service).toBeDefined();
  });

  it('showContents should return true for an Admin Role', (done) => {
    const attributes = {
      roles: ['ROLE_ADMIN'],
    };
    service.getUserAttributes().subscribe((state) => {
      expect(state.attributes).toEqual(attributes);
      done();
    });
    spyOn(userServiceSpy, 'onUserEvent').and.returnValue(of(attributes));
    service.getUserAttributes(); // invoke after
    expect(service.getUserAttributes).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

This is my TS

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class UserRolesProvider implements HotjarUserAttributesLoader {
  constructor(private userService: UserService) {}

  getUserAttributes(): Observable<HotjarUserAttributes> {
    return this.userService.onUserEvent().pipe(
      map((user) => {
        return {
          id: user.id,
          attributes: {
            roles: user.roles,
          },
        };
      })
    );
  }
}
```

And this is the user Service.

```
 private userEvent$ = new ReplaySubject<User>(1);

 onUserEvent(): ReplaySubject<User> {
    return this.userEvent$;
  }
```

HotJarUserAttributes it is an interface

```
export interface HotjarUserAttributes {
    id: string;
    attributes: any;
}
```

Comment: Do you really need done function? Also I would suggest you to call and.returnValue calls in the beginning off each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have spied the dependency using the below line:

```
userServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('UserService', ['onUserEvent']);
```

but you have not specified what this observable will return. As I can see you are returning an object of type user which has two properties `id` and `roles` in your component code.
You can fix the issue by returning same type in test case as well. Just add the below line after your spy creation.

```
const returnedObject: HotjarUserAttributes = {
  id: '1',
  attributes: { roles: [1, 2] },
}

userServiceSpy.onUserEvent.and.returnValue(of(returnedObject))
```

Comment: Now I get an error which says `LOG LOG: Object{id: '1', attributes: Object{roles: undefined}}, 'state' ` ,in code 35 which is this one here.

Comment: Please add a detailed error snippet, what is failing message in jasmine and what is the detailed explanation. I will suggest you to replace the returnedObject with the object you expect your observable to emit. I have just added this object as per my assumption